# Why do I need the `new` keyword for an instance of `Date` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, new-operator, operator-keyword

I understand the difference in *behavior*. `Date()` returns a String representing the current date, and `new Date()` returns an instance of the Date object whose methods I can call.

But I don't know *why*. JavaScript is prototyped, so `Date` is a function *and* an object which has member functions (methods) which are also objects. But I haven't written or read any JavaScript that behaves this way, and I'd like to understand the difference.

Can somebody show me some sample code of a function that has a method, returns an instance with the new operator, and outputs a String when called directly? i.e. how does something like this happen?

```
Date();                   // returns "Fri Aug 27 2010 12:45:39 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
new Date();               // returns Object
new Date().getFullYear(); // returns 2010
Date().getFullYear();     // throws exception!
```

Very specific request, I know. I hope that's a good thing. :)

Comment: Re *why*: it's an unfortunate hangover from the original JavaScript implementation that made it into the ECMAScript spec: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.2

Comment: Ooh! Thanks. I love context and history. That's good _why_. :)

Comment: Thanks @Crescent. I've incorporated this into my answer for completeness.

Comment: **YAY, TEAMWORK!** Thanks guys. I really get this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of this is possible to do yourself. Calling the bare constructor without `new` and getting a string is special for `Date` per the ECMA spec, but you can simulate something similar for that.

Here's how you'd do it. First declare an object in the constructor pattern (e.g. a function that is intended to be called with `new` and which returns its `this` reference:

```
var Thing = function() {
    // Check whether the scope is global (browser). If not, we're probably (?) being
    // called with "new". This is fragile, as we could be forcibly invoked with a 
    // scope that's neither via call/apply. "Date" object is special per ECMA script,
    // and this "dual" behavior is nonstandard now in JS. 
    if (this === window) { 
        return "Thing string";
    }

    // Add an instance method.
    this.instanceMethod = function() {
        alert("instance method called");
    }

    return this;
};
```

New instances of Thing can have `instanceMethod()` called on them. Now just add a "static" function onto Thing itself:

```
Thing.staticMethod = function() {
    alert("static method called");
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
var t = new Thing(); 
t.instanceMethod();
// or...
new Thing().instanceMethod();
// and also this other one..
Thing.staticMethod();
// or just call it plain for the string:   
Thing();
```

Comment: But `Thing()` doesn't do anything in a static context. Does Date just detect whether its being called in a static context and return a String instead of an Object? If so, how?

Comment: See update. That's a great question. Per @Crescent's comment on the original question, it looks like `Date` is special. You can achieve something like this yourself as above, but please don't. It's not a common usage idiom in JS.

Comment: You might want to add a little to the comment for future viewers? Like "invoked with a scope that's neither, such as with .map() or .apply()" Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

`new` is a keyword in Javascript (and others) to create a new instance of an object.
Possibly duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript).
See also this article: http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Understanding_the_JavaScript_new_keyword

Comment: Just a guess here, but I don't think the issue here is that new will return and object.  Rather it is the fact that Date() can be called without first creating an instance.  (for limited usage, I admit)  To get the full date functionality, you need to create an instance with new.

Comment: I know what `new` does (and I think I made this clear in my question). I don't know why the function behaves differently when called as a constructor and as a static function. I want to know the syntax that causes this distinction.